# Do all 汉字 components (radicals and non-radicals) have names?

Tags: radicals, characters

I would like to know, so all radicals and non-radicals that make up Chinese character have names?

If so, then where can I find a radical and non-radical Chinese character component dictionary?

I was thinking, that if someone was teaching, they may want to use name (and perhaps also 的-descriptions, for disambiguation), when teaching them.

This would also have the advantage, of, adding visually impaired people understand, the various components a character was made up of, which might help explain its meaning, a pronunciation clue, or even, which I think would be very nice, a story related to the parts that make up a character.

In theory, it would be nice to have a Braille system, where a long sequence of Braille characters, told the user on a Braille device (which could also speak), the exact components and layout of these radical and non-radical components.

After all, blind users may be curious.

[image: Braillant display picture]

Comment: cf。＂教学汉字规范手册＂ISBN７－１０７－１２６９４－６，汉字的笔画及笔画名称（３１,named at this site before)，汉字的部件及较难称说部件的名称（第１３页－第３２页）（e。g。偏旁：二，名称：二字头，例字：元云亓）汉字的部首及部首名称（第３３页－第３９页）（e。g。部首：阝，名称：双耳部）

Comment: Sorry, my Chinese is not advanced enough to be able to red this. Is there a Chinese or Chineseand English resource online accessible to learners. I don't think I have a way to grab a good of the book. Thanks.

Comment: search web using e。g。＂汉字的部件的名称＂：one result with table: http://www.elitechinese.org/chinesestructure.pdf,  for names of the 31 strokes search web using e.g. "汉字的笔画及笔画名称" -> http://torontomandarinschool.com/download/chinese_writing_strokes.pdf

Comment: Short answer is, yes there is, and it's a important part of early education (first a few years in elementary school). Chinese-Chinese directories also has a index to look up characters by component, to solve the problem that "How do I find out how to pronounce that strange symbol?" or "How am I suppose to look it up in the dictionary if I don't know the pinyin" kind of chicken-egg problem.

Comment: Hi user6065. I was aware of the stiff in the second document. I am looking for something more extensive than the very very short list outlined in the first document. Thanks.

Comment: How is the picture related?

Comment: The picture is there to provoke thought about how radicals may be presented to blind users using a Braille display. I have a Braille document which suggests blind users just rely on a Braille version of pinyin to learn Chinese, but, if they could see the radicals and character components as well somehow, that would certainly be nice.

Comment: keep searching web using e.g. 汉字部件名称, one result with 43 names:http://wenku.baidu.com/view/cb49ad2058fb770bf78a550e.html### -> longer list with 汉字常用偏旁部首名称表 http://wenku.baidu.com/view/451f66045727a5e9856a618b.html

Answer (score 1):

http://www.zdic.net/z/jbs/

try this website, it's helped me when i see a character but don't know how to pronounce it. it tells you what the radical and non-radical is called as well. hope it helps you.

Comment: It seems to me some radicals and non-radicals have names, and some do not.

Comment: is it possible to paste the radicals / non radicals you're referring to here? i'll see if there are other websites available.